# htaccess rewrite domain prefix abc.domainname.com to xyz.domainname.com

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to convert my current prefix value to another prefix value, basically text rename. For eg abc.domainname.com to xyz.domainname.com

Below is what I have tried so far.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xyz.domainname\.com/%1
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: With the above code, when I attempt renaming abc.domainname.com to xyz.domainname.com, it still stays on abc.domainname.com rather than xyz.domainname.com

Comment: Your condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc\.` prevents prevents the rule's redirection. Just remove the `!` char from the pattern or change it to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.`